# Unable to insert data in the table residing in SQLite database in my android app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Kindly note that I am designing an app which involves creation of database on running for first time and simply opening it in the runs to follow.So I have handled it the following way in my 'MainActiviy' class in 'onCreate()' method:

```
try 
{
    myDataBase=this.openOrCreateDatabase("wishes", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    myDataBase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tablename
                 +
                " (_id VARCHAR(15) primary key,Name VARCHAR(20), Message VARCHAR(100),Event VARCHAR(15),Date INT);");

}    //SQLiteDatabase 'myDatabase' is declared as public
```

Now I have another class called 'eventdefinition' wherein I create 'MainActivity' object 'ma' and then I try to insert the values in table on button click event as follows:

```
              MainActivity ma=new MainActivity();     //line 63
              event=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();   //line 64
              message=ed1.getText().toString();    //line 65
              ma.myDataBase.openDatabase("/data/data/org.mithil.autowish/databases/wishes", null,ma.myDataBase.OPEN_READWRITE);   //line 66
              ma.myDataBase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +        
                        ma.tablename +
                        " Values ('"+ finalnumber +"','"+ name +"','"+ message +"','"+ event +"','"+ ldate +"');");
```

The code is giving me NullPointerException as follows:

`05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at org.mithil.autowish.eventdefinition$2.onClick(eventdefinition.java:67)
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-10 11:03:30.992: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Please let me know where I am doing it wrong.Any assistance will mean a lot.Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Just use ORMLight, DB work in Android is a pain, ORMLite makes it easier.

Comment: your error is `java.lang.NullPointerException` mean getting null value @ here `OnClick(eventdefinition.java:67` DEBUG once

Comment: Sprinkle your code with some debug statements and see which of your values is giving you the null.  Add Log.d("finalNumber = " + finalNumber); etc.

Comment: thanks guys for suggestions    @Mars:I will try your method right away and let you know the result.Thanks

Comment: The error is int the nullpointerexception somewhere in your onClick, nothing to do with database.

Comment: @MarsAtomic : I tried your method however I am not still not able to narrow down the region of discrepancy.I did Log.d...,as you suggested, on my variables and they are returning accurate values

Comment: I think I see a problem... why are you creating an instance of MainActivity?  I would assume that there's a MainActivity running already that has a reference to myDatabase.  The null is coming because you created a second instance which has no reference to myDatabase at all.  I think your code needs some serious rearchitecture.  Try to add a debug statement that prints out the reference to myDatabase and I bet that's where your code blows up.

Comment: @MarsAtomic:It seems that there was a problem with referencing.I declared myDatabase as static and could reference it by 'MainActivity.myDatabase'.Thanks a lot for all the help.Apologies for any inconvenience. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate this out from your activity. The easiest method is to implement a single dao that extends the SQLiteOpenHelper class.

Java doc here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

This class has built in logic to create a new database or update the database based on the version so you don't have to re-implement logic in the activity to do the database creation.

All you need to do is implement the onCreate(db) method and onUpdate(db, oldVer, newVer) methods.

Comment: This answer is actually not bad, probably only incomplete -- understandable, given that we can't see the totality of what the OP is trying to accomplish.  I suspect there have to be many more changes to the structure of his code.  One upvote to cancel the downvote given by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

To handle all queries related database in Android, you can go for this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) here. It tells you how to create/drop table and it also tell you how to iterate/insert/delete/update data from android database.

I hope it helps you.